# Customizing user feeds in chat

Tags: feature-request, support, comments, chat, feed

Currently, if I add a [user feed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/4421) to a chat room, I get a onebox that pops up every time there is a user action.  The onebox contains either the *question* or the *answer* referenced in the feed entry.

But the feed also contains *comments* by the given user.  When a user comments on a question/answer, I get a onebox in chat, but it displays a *question* or *answer*, with no indication about how it connects to the given user.  I have to click through to determine that the user commented.

If there are multiple user feeds in one chat room, it can make it very confusing to know which feed a post is coming from.

Which brings me to my question(s):

***Can I customize the way a user feed is posted to chat, so that the `<title>` and/or `<summary>` portion of the XML is displayed?***

This will make it much easier to understand from which feed the post is coming. (If the entry is a comment, the `<title>` tag contains something like "Comment by GentlePurpleRain on *Question X*", and the `<summary>` tag contains the actual comment.)

Failing that,

***Can I filter a user feed so that only questions and/or answers are displayed in chat, and comments are ignored?***

If neither of these are possible, can this be implemented?

Comment: Wow. I didn't even know it was possible to make a feed to track a user's activity. What would this be useful for? (other than stalking people :-P )

Comment: @randal'thor It has been used by Puzzling mods to keep an eye on activity of users who have had consistently low-quality posts or who have been disruptive, in order to be able to react more quickly if such activity persists. I could also see it being used as a way to "follow" someone whose posts you really appreciate.

Comment: Is this mod only, or can anybody do it?  Creeptastic either way.

Comment: @Won't [Anyone can do it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/1228).  It's the same info available on the user's public profile page.