# Comments from user feed link to the parent post instead; confusing onebox in the chat room

Tags: bug, comments, chat, feed, onebox

Recently, we (moderators on Android.SE) started adding some users' feed to our mod's chat room for moderation purposes. After a while, the users' posts were onebox-ed as expected, but then seemingly unrelated posts were too. After a quick-peek to the feed's content, we realized that it also contains the user's comments.

For illustrative purposes (click the image for full-version):

[image]

Here are 2 samples of the feed entry for the comment, one for the question:

```
<entry>
    <id>https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347348/why-can-i-not-log-in-to-stack-exchange-android-app-using-a-google-account?cid=1162608</id>
    <title type="text">Comment by Meta Andrew T. on Why can I not log in to Stack Exchange Android app using a Google account?</title>
    <...>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347348/why-can-i-not-log-in-to-stack-exchange-android-app-using-a-google-account" />
    <...>
</entry>
```

And another for the answer:

```
<entry>
    <id>https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339029/as-a-workaround-to-imgur-being-blocked-is-there-a-image-hosting-site-which-allo/339035?cid=1132328#339035</id>
    <title type="text">Comment by Meta Andrew T. on As a workaround to Imgur being blocked, is there a image hosting site which allows URL uploads and does not violate CC BY-SA 4.0 copyright?</title>
    <...>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339029/as-a-workaround-to-imgur-being-blocked-is-there-a-image-hosting-site-which-allo/339035#339035" />
    <...>
</entry>
```

There are 2 URLs mentioned on the feed:

- `<id>`: the post's default URL, with `?cid=<comment_id>` added
- `<link>`: the post's default URL

While the `<link>` URL obviously will not redirect to the comment, apparently the `<id>` URL also does not, compared to the current comment's permalink with `#comment<comment_id>_<post_id>`:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347348/why-can-i-not-log-in-to-stack-exchange-android-app-using-a-google-account#comment1162608_347348
```

or the alternative using `/posts/comments/<comment_id>` used in the timeline:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1162608
```

Considering all of these, can the link to the comment on feed be replaced with the comment's permalink instead? Presumably, this will replace the post-onebox (confusing without context) into the comment-onebox (contains the comment, the user, and the permalink to the comment).

---

*[Customizing user feeds in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284308/customizing-user-feeds-in-chat) might be related, but not sure if it is a duplicate since this question focuses on fixing the comment's link instead (which might or might not help the linked feature-request)*

Comment: So, you want to filter what is and isn't picked up by the feed more specifically than you currently do, correct?

Comment: @Mast not really filter, since we are okay with comments on the feed (the linked FR is more about filtering/customizing). However, comments from the feed are currently onebox-ed to their parent post instead, not the comment directly. I believe this is because the link used in the feed is the post's link, not the comment's real link. At the very least, I prefer the onebox to directly link to the comment, presumably by fixing the URL.

Comment: For keeping an eye on comments, we use [a workaround](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51786/duga) in The 2nd. We use that to properly onebox comments, like [this random example](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=54379206#54379206).

Comment: Related: [Answer Only RSS feed for a user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14183/269301)

Comment: Related: [Customizing user feeds in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284308/269301)